# Styeling an SSL certificate logo

Tags: javascript, html, ssl

I have recently added a comodo ssl certificate to my website, to do so they gave me two javascript snippets to install on my website one that goes above the head of the document and one above the body
it has loaded succesfully but the image is huge even though i specified 100x85px version does anyone know how to style this element even thouh it has no anchor or tag i think its annoying that they want the code above the head and body as the Charset-UTF8 has to be within the first 28kb or 128kb i can't remember specifically but please help, i have looked on both namecheap website, youtube and other places

Comment: You can view my problem here  https://linxlibrary.app/

Comment: it also has an anchor link to comodo that i would preffer at the bottom of the page